# Jupyter notebook: 500 : surrogates not allowed

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

While running `jupyter notebook` in command in Ubuntu 18.04,  I get `http://localhost:8888/tree` on Chrome browser, but shows `500 : surrogates not allowed` on the web page.

Here is detailed error log from command. Someone know how to fix it? Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1510, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2898, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/tree/handlers.py", line 53, in get
    server_root=self.settings['server_root_dir'],
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 717, in write
    chunk = utf8(chunk)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 200, in utf8
    return value.encode("utf-8")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 4226-4231: surrogates not allowed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by:

```
export LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8
xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update --force
```